# What is the fastest way to reload history commands begin with certain characters in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

In Dos we can input the first several characters to filter command history and find proper one rapidly. But how to do the same thing in Linux ?

for example when I am testing a local server:

```
cd 
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd start
wget ...
ls
emacs ...
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd stop
...
```

In Dos you can easily type `sudo` and switch among the three commands beginning with it using arrow keys. But in Linux, is below command the best we can do ?

```
historty | grep sudo
```

I don't like it, because history can easily become a mess, and it also need mouse action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the following in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Then after typing `sudo`, <kbd>Up</kbd> will search for commands starting with `sudo`.

(You will have to restart bash.) (Unsure if this works in csh.)

Comment: The above works for anything using readline (python, gnuplot, gdb, ...). See http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.inputrc

Comment: @pixelbeat: maybe you should put the "`$include /etc/inputrc`" at top? Otherwise the system settings could override your customizations.

Answer (score 6):

In Bash (and most readline-based applications like it) you can press `Ctrl-R` to bring up a history search function:

```
$ date
Tue Feb  1 15:40:06 EET 2011
(reverse-i-search)`d': date
```

By pressing `Enter` here I get:

```
$ date
Tue Feb  1 15:40:06 EET 2011
$ date
Tue Feb  1 15:40:52 EET 2011
```

EDIT:

You can see the full list of history-related Bash keystrokes [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-History).

You can see the current list of history search keyboard bindings:

```
$ bind -P | grep search | grep history
forward-search-history can be found on "\C-s".
history-search-backward can be found on "\e[5~".
history-search-forward can be found on "\e[6~".
non-incremental-forward-search-history can be found on "\en".
non-incremental-forward-search-history-again is not bound to any keys
non-incremental-reverse-search-history can be found on "\ep".
non-incremental-reverse-search-history-again is not bound to any keys
reverse-search-history can be found on "\C-r".
```

In my case Page-Up/Down can also be used to search for commands that start with whatever I have already typed, as configured in my `/etc/inputrc`:

```
# Page Up/Down cycles through history only for matching entries
"\e[5~": history-search-backward       # Previous
"\e[6~": history-search-forward        # Next
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that by repeatedly pressing `CTRL-R` you search trough the list.

Comment: It seems this command only searches backward, right?

Comment: @gerry, yes `Ctrl-R` only searches backwards

Comment: @gerry: `Ctrl-S` searches forward, but you may need to do `stty -ixon` to enable it (and disable `Ctrl-S` and `Ctrl-Q` from stopping and starting data flow).

Comment: @Dennis Thank you. Your supplement is helpful. Now this answer may be the most complete usage of Ctrl-R on the web :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, you can type `!sudo` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in bash and it will execute the **last** command starting with `sudo`.

Comment: Quite useful... until *that* time where the last command is something along the lines of `sudo rm -rf *`. I know quite a few people that have been burnt like this.

Comment: @thkala: Maybe `sudo` is one of the commands that should *not* be used with this ;)

Comment: I find that `shopt -s histverify histreedit` helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the first letter like `sudo`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>.